# Is there any difference between "clear conscience" and "clean conscience"?

Tags: meaning, phrases, synonyms

> I want to have a **clear** conscience so that I know to judge clearly what is right or wrong.

*vs.*

> I want to have a **clean** conscience, therefore I will not do such an ugly thing.

The dictionary tells that 'clear conscience' is the same as 'clean conscience'. Both are idioms. However, my intuition is that a clear conscience is more about giving a clear judgment, whereas clean conscience is more about avoiding bad deeds and being free of guilt. I might agree that 'clear conscience' covers the two meanings, but I would say 'clean conscience' would better be restricted to the meaning as in the second example. Am I wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by “giving a clear judgment”? That makes no sense to me in the context of having a clear conscience. ‘Clear’ here does not refer to clarity or perspicacity, but to lack of clutter and having been cleared away; like a clear table, which is a table that all items have been removed from. A clean conscience and a clear conscience mean the exact same thing to me: while a cluttered table is not the same as a dirty table necessarily, there's no real way of making that (or the antonymic) distinction with a conscience.

Comment: Precisely the same as that between *clear* and *clean*. I could see the difference, can you?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+clean+table%2C+a+clear+table&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20clean%20table%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20clear%20table%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Well said! I totally agree!!! I was thinking about the same thing!

Answer (score 3):

In the context of conscience, *clear* does not necessarily have associations with negativity, it is merely being free of distractions. (*cf*. 'clear thought' *vs*. 'clean thought')

*Clean*, on the other hand, implies being free from negativity.

One with a clear conscience is not influenced by anything in his decision making.

One can have a clean conscience only when not tainted by misdeeds of the past.

As for the dictionary definition, the point could be that in actual usage the phrases are generally interchangeable and the distinction is too subtle in most contexts.

Answer (score 2):

I agree about a "clean" conscience being "untainted by misdeeds of the past" -- that is, without even the faintest tinge of wrong or ambiguous judgment. But "clear" conscience has always implied to me a looking-back over deeds and judgments that might have been questionable; and, upon reflection, they came up good. So, perhaps, a "cleared" conscience?